# Is there a bound for $|a+b|$ of the form $f(a,b) \leq |a+b|$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, absolute-value

$a,b$ are integers and the $f(a,b)$ is a function of $a$ and $b$.

I know that $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$. But what about $(? \leq |a+b|)$

Comment: $|a+b| \le |a|+|b| \implies |x+y-y| \le |x+y|+|-y|$.

Comment: That would be $0\leq |a+b|$, which is also the best possible since you can have $b=-a$.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the reverse triangle inequality: $$||a|-|b|| \leq |a-b|.$$

Comment: No @amWhy. The OP stated that "they know $|a+b|\le |a|+|b|$", confusing the triangle inequality (the one they provide is just an equality). The OP isn't asking about $||a|-|b||$, nor is D.B. suggesting that...

Comment: Got it; sorry for my confusion.

Comment: @RhysHughes  The comment above, I guess, should be directed to you.  I thought it was from D.B.  In any case, to both of you, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is this valid for real numbers $a,b$? Why the minus sign at $|a-b|$, could I just change to $|a+b|$?